# How can i have my code print more than one graph at a time?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv", skiprows=[1])
magnitudes = df['Magnitude '].values
times = df['Time '].values
zscores = np.abs(stats.zscore(magnitudes, ddof=1))
outlier_indicies = np.argwhere(zscores > 3).flatten()
print(times[outlier_indicies])


window = 10
num = 1
x = times[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]
y = magnitudes[outlier_indicies[num]-window:outlier_indicies[num]+window+1]


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time (units)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (units)')
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()


fig.savefig("/Users/aaronhuang/Downloads")
```

Is there a way I can print all the graphs separately once?. Deleting num has not worked.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the plots inside a for loop, and repeat as many times as you like, with different variables for each step if needed. Most software will show the plots either in multiple plot windows, or output them in a long strip you can scroll through. If you use Spyder however, they will play back to back, with each plot being a frame.

Also, if you want to print multiple plots, you have to put the `plt.show()` inside the loop as well, putting it after the loop will show all the values on a single plot.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for x in x_values:
    y = x**2
    plt.plot(x,y,"o")
    plt.axis([0,50, 0,50])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you be able to write out some of the code? I am quite new and unsure of where to start.

Comment: Here's an example!